# Spring Boot EnvironmentPostProcessor overriding Command Line

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am using an [EnvironmentPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/EnvironmentPostProcessor.html), in particular the [CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.html), in order to parse some environment variables and make them accessible as Spring properties.

When I run my application, the EnvironmentPostProcessor kicks in and creates the desired property variables as expected.

`@Value("${vcap.services.test-service.name}") /* Example of a property loaded from PostProcessor. Works fine. */`

However, when I try to set this property value explicitly using the command line, or properties file, the value that I specify does not override the value that is being populated by the EnvironmentPostProcessor. I would expect that overriding this property via the command line should take precedence.

`vcap.services.test-service.name=TEST_VALUE` Does not override.

Essentially, there seems to be **nothing** I can do in order to override the value set by this EnvironmentPostProcessor (command line, profiles, .properties files, spring.factories order definitions, etc)

Is there any way to override a property value created in an EnvironmentPostProcessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by `CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor` adding a property source with a precedence that's higher than the method you're using to override properties:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.java#L126-L135

There is that block that sets this lower than command line args, were you using command line args or -D system properties?

You could try adding `spring-boot-starter-actuator` and hit the /env endpoint to see all property sources and their precedence, those appearing first have higher precedence than those appearing further down in the JSON. As a last resort you can create your own `EnvironmentPostProcessor` that's `Ordered` to execute after `CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor`, that creates a property source with highest precedence.